# Java method naming conventions

Tags: java

This question is composed of two simple ones:

1. Is the latest document on Java naming conventions, the 1999 doc available at [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)?
2. How would you call a method whose sole purpose is to create a new instance of a complex class called, for example, `XmlError`? `createXmlError()`? `generateXmlError()`? `getXmlError()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get methods *usually* mean 'get me the value of a field` such as;

```
int getTotal() {
    return total;
}
```

For methods that construct and return a new object, what you're talking about there is pretty much a `Factory`. The factories in the Java API use several naming conventions; `createXXX` `makeXXX` `generateXXX` all appear in one standard-edition factory or another.

I would say use whichever makes most sense to you, and stick to it. Save `get` and `set` for simple field operations though.

Comment: `total` could be a field as in your example or it could be a simple calculation like `return orderTotal + shippingAndHandling + salesTax;` or it could involve something complex like a database query.  As the user of your code, I don't really care, but I don't want you changing method names just because of implementation changes.

Comment: you're quite right, although in my personal conventions, anything much beyond returning a direct field value gets called `calculateXXX()`, I try to stick with `get`, `set`, `put`, `poll` types of strictness.

Comment: what about the second question, is there any Java naming convention document newer than the 1999 one?

Comment: not that i'm aware of i'm afraid. the one thing that really matters is capitalisation, summarised here > http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: @Pomario The 1999 version appears to be the last official one.  I did quite some googling last year trying to find a newer one (and some quick ones just now) but couldn't find any.

Comment: @lynks my concern is if your implementation changes from simple field to simple calculation ... (1) if you change the method name, then I as user have to keep somewhat keep track of your implementation details; (2) if you don't change, then over time you will stop following your own convention.  (But if your users are happy with things then everything is A-OK.)

Answer (score 0):

Your create() and generate() examples seem reasonable. I wouldn't worry too much about it unless you're producing an API for wide dissemination.

Answer (score -1):

1. If you are using a `singleton` class, then `getInstance()` is the
   convention i think.
2. Otherwise just extend the `Exception` class you want to generate, and
   throw it.